# How to fetch category name of a venue from result object of fouresquare venue search?

Tags: ios, cordova, foursquare

I am developing an ios app using phonegap in which I am using foursquare venue search api for listing all the near by venues.

This is the code I have used to list the name of all the near by venues.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll='+pos+'&radius=10000&client_id=2POUFAUU4ZBJ2MTDOY3S2YHR2NIT52FYW0LUTPHBMNTJFJNQ&client_secret=YFDZI1YWV3ZI5S5SPM2DZJEQIEBPIDJ5XFZBWTIKIQZVQNYM&v=20120101&limit=60',
          function(data) {

          console.log(pos);
          $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
                             content = '<li id="list-item"> <p><a href="#reviewPage" onClick="reviewPageAction(this)">' + venues.name + '</li>';
                 /*$(content).appendTo("#names");*/

                 $(content).appendTo("#mer");

                 });
          });
```

And now my problem is , I want to display the category name with name of each venue. I have tried the following code

```
venues.categories.name
```

but it didn't work.

Is it possible to fetch the category name of each venue.?? Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

The Venues endpoint will return all the categories assigned to a venue. There can be multiple categories assigned to a venue, one of the categories will have a field "primary" that is set to true to indicate that it is the primary category.

Look for something like this in the result set:

```
categories: [
{
  id: "4bf58dd8d48988d143941735",
  name: "Breakfast Spot",
  pluralName: "Breakfast Spots",
  shortName: "Breakfast",
  icon: {
  prefix: "https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/breakfast_",
  suffix: ".png"
},
  primary: true
},
{
  id: "4bf58dd8d48988d16a941735",
  name: "Bakery",
  pluralName: "Bakeries",
  shortName: "Bakery",
  icon: {
  prefix: "https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/bakery_",
  suffix: ".png"
},
}
}
]
```